# Is it possible to run a Google Sheets Add-on using an Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, add-on

I would like to set a time trigger on an add-on in google sheets. Considering it doesn't have one as part of it, I was going to write an Apps Script to run it and set a trigger to the script. Is this possible or is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Its not possible as we cannot execute the code in Google sheets

Answer (score 2):

Add on and bound apps script will run in different projects. It is currently not possible to trigger add-on project function from bound apps script.